# OpenMP performance issues with Matrix Multiplication (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, openmp, matrix-multiplication

I have been trying to parallelize my code about Matrix Multiplication with OpenMP.

```
void multiplicacionMatriz(const vector<vector<int> > &A, const vector<vector<int> > &B, vector<vector<int> > &C)
{
    if(A[0].size() != B.size())
    {
        cerr << "No se pueden multiplicar las matrices." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    unsigned int i, j, k, filasA, columnasB, comun;
    filasA = A.size();
    columnasB = B[0].size();
    comun= A[0].size(); 

    // PARELELIZACIÓN BUCLE FOR
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) num_threads(8)
    for (i = 0; i < filasA; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columnasB; j++)
        {
            // C[i][j] = 0; Ya inicializados a 0
            for (k = 0; k < comun; k++) 
            {
                C[i][j] = C[i][j] + (A[i][k] * B[k][j]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been testing it with different matrix sizes, and I've been getting good results for now (averages of many runs):

- 1000x1000: 5 seconds instead of 20.
- 1500x1500: 20 seconds instead of 80.
- 2000x2000: 25 seconds onstead of 200.

I've tried testing it with some bigger matrix sizes but the multiplication time doens't increase as expected... it decreases: I've gotten 15 seconds for 2500x2500 and 3 seconds for 5000x5000 instead of an hour!
I get the following results for bigger sizes (these have been tried once or twice only):

- 7500x7500: 9 seconds.
- 10000x10000: 38 seconds.
- 15000x15000: 59 seconds.

Is this normal? How can I be multiplicating two 7500x7500 matrices faster than two 2000x2000. I wasn't expecting these results and I'm quite lost right now. Any insight is appreciated!

**Matrix initialization**

Each matrix is a vector of vector. I initialize every value at 0.

```
// Pedimos la dimensión de las matrices a procesar.
cout << "Inserte la dimensión (cuadrada) de la matriz: ";
cin >> dimension;

// Matrices auxiliares
vector<vector<int> > A(dimension, std::vector<int>(dimension,0)), B(dimension, std::vector<int>(dimension,0)), C(dimension, std::vector<int>(dimension,0));
vector<vector<int> > CModificado(dimension, std::vector<int>(dimension,0));
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've changed my code so I only collapse the inner loops of the loops and it's been working fine for greater values.

```
// PARELELIZACIÓN BUCLE FOR
//#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) num_threads(8)
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filasA; i++) 
{
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) num_threads(8)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < columnasB; j++)
    {
        // C[i][j] = 0; Ya inicializados a 0
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < comun; k++) 
        {
            C[i][j] = C[i][j] + (A[i][k] * B[k][j]); 
        }
    }
}
```

This gives results somewhat more normal, with time increasing gradually and not so irreguarly as before

- 1000x1000 in 5.2 seconds average
- 1500x1500 in 20 seconds average
- 2000x2000 in 48.2 seconds average
- 2500x2500 in 100 seconds average

Comment: Are those results of a single run or an average of several tests?

Comment: Average of several, except for the bigger ones I've tried right now.

Comment: collapse(3) would make no sense if you don't get correct results.  You may be overflowing signed int with your total loop count for 3 levels.  It would make more sense to allow your compiler to optimize vectorization between the 2 inner levels, at least in the case where A.size is several times the number of cores available.

Comment: @tim18 Thank you for the input! I've changed my code following what you said. Collapsing only the inner loops seems to work for greater values, obtaining values closer to what I expected.

Comment: Did you ever check whether the result of your computation is still correct after parallelization? I doubt it is. You need to make the indexes you use to run through your matrices thread local. The easiest way to do this would be to declare them in the header of the for loops like `for(unsigned int j; j< columnasB; j++)`. I noticed you commented the line where you initialize C[i][j] to 0. Why? Are you always sure that C is only filled with 0 when you call your function?

Comment: @PaulR. Thank you for the answer. Well, I've been checking for lower matrix sizes (up to 4x4) and it seems to work fine. 
The line is commented because I initialize all the matrix values to 0 when I create them (I do this in another function on the code), with the vector constructor.